# How do I divide this string after the word extracted with the regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, validation

```py
import re

input_text_to_checkA = "to play football in the street you need good boots" #For example

regex_patron_00A = r"\s*\¿?(?:so you can play |so you can play |to play the |to play )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
regex_patron_00B = r" \s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:are really necessary the |are really necessary |would be needed from |would be needed |she needs |he needs |you need )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
mA = re.search(regex_patron_00A, input_text_to_checkA, re.IGNORECASE)
if mA:
    input_text_to_checkB = mA.group() # ---> "football in the street you need good boots"

    mB = re.search(regex_patron_00B, input_text_to_checkB, re.IGNORECASE)
    if mB:
        word, association = m.groups()
        word = word.strip() # ---> "football in the street"
        association = association.strip() # ---> "good boots"
```

I need `input_text_to_checkB = ""` to store the string without the beginning of what was valid in the first regex and without what was stored in the word variable.

Comment: You have indentation errors that should be corrected. You should also make it clearer what you expect the actual output string value should be.

Comment: @Booboo Sure indentation errors were made when copying code snippets and removing unnecessary stuff. What I need is that in input_text_to_checkB it has the initial input string but without the match of the first regex and without the word word, for example if input_text_to_checkA is equal to "to play football in the street you need good boots" it is necessary to remove the match "to play" and what was stored in word "football in the street".

Comment: It's still not too clear. You should be updating the question with clarifications by adding a print statement of the variable you would be  outputting and indicating what it's value should be. And why not fix the indentation errors while you are at it?. Somebody has posted an edit request to fix your indentation problem but one should never second-guess the OP's intentions. **Also, your regex  `regex_patron_00A` matches the *entire* string `input_text_to_checkA`, i.e. mA.group() will be the complete string not 'football in the street',  so if you remove what matches you have nothing left.**

Comment: There I have edited it, and I improved the code that now almost works so that I have `word = "to play football in the street"` and `association = "good boots"`, only `word` is wrong because it would be necessary to remove the match that occurred in `regex_patron_00A` leaving only ` word = "football in the street"`.